# Norm Equality for Map and Adjoint Map on Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Case:

[image]

for which I was studying first the case with $X,Y$ as Hilbert spaces but then later with $X,Y$ as Banach spaces. 
I am interested on the rigorous proof. 
I think the linearity and continuity should be also proven for the equation.

### My Proposal

Let $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, and let $A \in \mathscr{B}(X,Y)$ be fixed.
For any $u \in X$ and $\psi \in Y'$ so $Au \in Y$: 
        \begin{align*}
  \langle Au, \psi \rangle &= \psi(Au) \\
  &= (\psi \circ A)(u) \\
  &= \langle u,(\psi \circ A) \rangle  \\
  &= \langle u, \psi' \rangle,
  \end{align*}
    so $\psi' = \psi \circ A$. Because $\langle u, \psi \circ A \rangle$, $u \in X$ and $\psi \circ A \in X'$.
    So $(\psi \circ A)$ is the wanted mapping $A' : Y' \to X'$. 
    So $\psi \in Y'$ and $A'(\psi) = (\psi \circ A)$. 
    Then for any $u \in X$ holds: 
    \begin{align*}
 \langle u, A'\psi \rangle (\in \mathbb{K}) &= \langle u, \psi \circ A \rangle \\
 &= (\psi \circ A)(u) \\
 &= \psi(Au) \\
 &= \langle Au, \psi \rangle \in \mathbb{K}
 \end{align*}
    and because $u \in X$ and $(\psi \circ A) = A' \in X'$.
    Also $A': Y' \to X'$ because selecting any $\psi \in Y'$ gets $A'(\psi) = (\psi \circ A) \in X'$.
    So $A': \psi (\in Y') \to \psi \circ A (\in X')$ and $A' \in \mathscr{B}(Y',X')$.

We want to show that there exists a unique operator $A' \in \mathscr{B}(Y', X')$ that satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\forall x \in X, \, \forall \varphi \in Y', \, \langle Ax, \varphi \rangle = \langle x, A' \varphi \rangle. 
\end{equation*}

Fix $\varphi' \in Y'$. 
Let the adjoint map $A' \varphi : X \to \mathbb{F}$ such that $\langle x, A' \varphi \rangle = \langle A x, \varphi \rangle$ for $x \in X$.

The linearity and continuity. 
Let $\varphi_{1}, \varphi_{2}, \varphi \in Y$, $x_{1}, x_{2}, x \in X$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$: 
\begin{align*}
\langle A' (\varphi_{1} + \varphi_{2}), x \rangle &= \langle \varphi_{1} + \varphi_{2}, Ax \rangle \\
&= \langle A' \varphi_{1} + A' \varphi_{2}, x \rangle \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\langle A'(\lambda \varphi), x \rangle &= \langle \lambda \varphi, Ax \rangle \\
&= \bar{\lambda} \langle \varphi, Ax \rangle \\
&= \langle \lambda A' \varphi, x \rangle
\end{align*}

Let's prove that $\|A'\| = \|A\|$.
If $Y = \{ 0 \}$, then $A = 0$ and $A' = 0$. 
Therefore, assume $Y \neq \{ 0 \}$. 
By Hahn-Banach, also $Y' \neq \{ 0 \}$. 
Choose any $x \in X$ with $\| x \| = 1$. 
Suppose that $Ax \neq 0$. Let $\varphi \in Y'$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
\langle Ax, \varphi \rangle = \| Ax \|, \, \| \varphi \| = 1.
\end{equation*}
If $Ax = 0$, then $\varphi \in Y'$ such that $A'\varphi = 0$. 
Then, 
\begin{align*}
\| Ax \| &= \langle x, A' y \rangle \\
&\leq \| A' y' \| \| x \| \\
&\leq \|A'\| \| x \| \\
&= \|A'\|
\end{align*}
So $\| Ax \| \leq \| A' \|$ and $\|A\| \leq \|A'\|$. 
Therefore, $\| A \| = \| A' \|$. $\square$

Sources

- Functional Analysis An introduction to Metric Spaces, Hilbert Spaces, and Banach Algebras by J. Muscat, 2014, p. 188, definition 10.19.
- Functional Analysis Lecture Notes: Adjoints in Banach Spaces, C. Heil, filename *[adjoint_banach.pdf](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/adjoint_banach.pdf)*
- Chapter 3: Duality in Banach Space, [www4.ncsu.edu/~mtchu/Teaching/Lectures/MA719/chapter3.ps](https://www.google.lv/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDYQFjAEahUKEwi1iOnizY_IAhWITBQKHb7nAhE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww4.ncsu.edu%2F~mtchu%2FTeaching%2FLectures%2FMA719%2Fchapter3.ps&usg=AFQjCNHVxZnbWyNau1utN0WBtR4pdaKwHg&bvm=bv.103388427,d.bGg&cad=rja)

---

How can you show the adjoint of an operator A on Banach spaces?

Comment: The part from "Let's prove that $||A'|| = ||A||$" till the end contains several small mistakes. First , you have to justify the existence of a functional $\varphi\in Y^{'}$ whose action on $Ax$ gives the norm $||Ax||$. It is certainly not true for every $\varphi \in Y^{'}$. Second, it is not true that $||Ax||\leq ||A'||$ for all $x$. Thirdly, $||A||\leq A'$ is missing the norm on the r.h.s.  Otherwise you are in the right direction.

Comment: 3rd iteration on the proof by starting from the definition.